# Understanding a value of *ngIf in Angular2

Tags: angular

I am an enthusiastic newbie trying to understand better Angular2. I would like to make a condition.

What Do I want to do? 
Disabled the first option of a dropdown.

What is the conditional? 
If var is equal to XX add disabled

Data

```
export class SuperComponent {
  moon = ['Select One Option', 'Option 1', 'Option 2','Option 3'];
}
```

Template

```
<option *ngFor="let OptionsList of moon" *ngIf="OptionsList==='Select One Option'" disabled>
  <span>{{OptionsList}}</span>
</option>
```

so, any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `*ngIf` in this situation, you can use attribute binding. Simply:

```
<option *ngFor="let OptionsList of moon" [attr.disabled]="OptionsList==='Select One Option'">
  <span>{{OptionsList}}</span>
</option>
```

And, since `disabled` is an attribute and a property of `option`, even shorter:

```
<option *ngFor="let OptionsList of moon" [disabled]="OptionsList==='Select One Option'">
  <span>{{OptionsList}}</span>
</option>
```

Comment: If you do [att.disabled]="false" or "true" this attribute will always attached to the `<option disabled="false"></option>`. Bootstrap's CSS actually uses disabled as a flag exists or not exists, so you can run into a trouble with this solution.

Comment: I see, that's a very important info for those who use bootstrap.Also, strange of bootstrap to not take the value into account. Thanks @AndreyKartashov

Comment: You are welcome @rodboc,  if you are using bootstrap CSS. Please take Andrey Kartashov's comment into consideration.

Answer (score 2):

ngIf will remove whole component `<option></option>` if the result is true. To add actually `<option disabled></option>` I would suggest next approach.

To use disabled it has to be injected so at first I would make a directive

```
@Directive({
selector: '[sdDisabled]',
})
export class sdDisabled {
@Input('sdDisabled') isDisabled: boolean;

constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

@Input() set sdDisabled(condition: boolean) {
    if (condition) {
        this.el.nativeElement.setAttribute('disabled');
    } else {
        this.el.nativeElement.removeAttribute('disabled');
    }
}
```

}

Now you can use [sdDisabled] to attach disables property

```
<option *ngFor="let OptionsList of moon" [sdDisabled]="OptionsList==='Select One Option'">
  <span>{{OptionsList}}</span>
</option>
```